# Defining a bijective mapping between a proper subset of $\mathbb N$ and a proper subset of $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N.$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, functions

> Let $m$ and $n$ be two positive integers. Show that there exists a bijection
> between the sets $R=\{r\in\mathbb N:1\le r\le mn,\gcd(r,mn)=1\}$ and
> $S=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb N\times\mathbb N:1\le a\le m,1\le b\le n,\gcd(a,m)=1,\gcd(b,n)=1\}.$

**My attempt:** It is clear that the cardinality of $R$ equals $\phi(mn),$ where $\phi(.)$ is the Euler's totient function, and also the cardinality of $S$ equals $\phi(m)\phi(n).$ Now, assuming that $m$ and $n$ are *coprime* to each other, we get: $\phi(mn)=\phi(m)\phi(m).$

That is to say that: $|R|=|S|.$ Hence there definitely exists a bijection between the sets $R$ and $S$.

Actually I want to define a bijective mapping between the sets in question. At first I thought of a map of the form: $r\mapsto (a,b)$ but nothing ensures this map to be a bijection, in general. So please help me to define the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Why can you assume that $m,n$ are coprime? (I don't see any condition in the problem) 2. Suppose $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then Chinese Remainder Thm gives you a ring isomorphism $\Bbb Z_{mn}\to\Bbb Z_m\times\Bbb Z_n$, which maps units to units, and you can show that it restricts to a bijection between $R$ and $S$, since they characterize the units in these two rings.

Comment: I think there is definitely some condition missing. If you take $m=2$, $n=4$, then $R=\{1,3,5,7\}$, $S=\{(1,1),(1,3)\}$, and we have $|R|\neq |S|$.

Comment: Assuming the unwritten condition $(m,n)=1,$ send $r\mapsto (r\bmod m,r\bmod n).$ Show this is one-to-one and onto. (The latter is essentially the Chinese remainder theorem.)

Comment: Thank you every one for giving your precious time and pointing out the necessary things. I made an assumption while showing $|R|=|S|$ that $(m,n)=1$ and I thought it was implied since there exists a bijection between the two sets and this was my mistake. Few moments back, I also realized that the condition $(m,n)=1$ was missing while going through my copy. Probably our professor made some printing mistake while typesetting this question. Whatsoever now I have understood how to define the bijection in the case the required condition is given.